# Why is my Gitlab CE crashing every time I run a pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have self hosted Gitlab CE 13.4.6 and a GitLab Runner installed, via docker. Everything runs fine (I can do normal admin tasks, submit code, etc.), until I start a pipeline. Every time the pipeline runs, it will get through a job or two successfully but then Gitlab gives me the "There has been a structural integrity problem detected, please contact system administrator", and then crashes with a 500 error. It doesn't matter which project or pipeline I run, it always crashes sometime during the pipeline run (it never completes).

When I dig around the logs, I find this error in the gitlab-workhorse log:

`{"correlation_id":"awMp1EaZkh3","duration_ms":0,"error":"badgateway: failed to receive response: dial unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket: connect: no such file or directory","level":"error","method":"POST","msg":"error","time":"2020-11-13T03:24:15Z","uri":"/api/v4/jobs/request"}`

I am running the latest version of docker for Mac (19.03), and below is my docker-compose. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong with the install?

````
version: "3.8"
services:
  gitlab-web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.4.6-ce.0'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.home.app'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.home.app'
        #I configured SSL manually
        letsencrypt['enable'] = false
        registry_external_url 'https://gitlab.home.app:5005'
        registry_nginx['enable'] = true
        registry_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = '/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.home.app.crt'
        registry_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = '/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.home.app.key'
        registry_nginx['listen_port'] = '5005'
        registry_nginx['listen_https'] = true
        gitlab_workhorse['auth_socket'] = '/var/tmp/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket'
    ports:
       - '80:80'
       - '443:443'
       - '8822:22'
       - '5005:5005'
    volumes:
      - './srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - './srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - './srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    dns:
      - 192.168.1.224
    networks:
      - gitlab
  
  gitlab-runner:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:v13.5.0'
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - 'gitlab-web'
    dns:
      - 192.168.1.224
    volumes:
      - './srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
      - './runner-cert:/usr/share/ca-certificates'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    networks:
      - gitlab

networks:
  gitlab:
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was a problem with docker's storage driver and how it was storing data on my local volume. I moved to a linux VM and it worked fine.